# Background Execution Limits on Oreo

Tags: android, android-service, android-8.0-oreo

Hi all Android geeks out there,

I am developing an Android application targetting Android Oreo (O).

```
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 27
```

I know there are limits for running background services, and I am able to overcome them by using [`startForeground(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)) method of service.

My doubt is;
Should I use this `startForeground(...)` method for all android versions? Since calling this method will display a notification I would like to avoid it in pre-Oreo versions if possible.

So, to avoid displaying notifications in pre-Oreo devices can I use the code snippet below? Will it work in the background for both pre and post Oreo?

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O /* 26 */) {
        // Make the service as foreground service by calling startForeground method
    } else {
        // Nothing to do
    }
```

---

To summarize my question:

- `targetSdkVersion 27` and `minSdkVersion 21`
- `MyService` should be run in background in both **pre Oreo** and **post Oreo** OS versions
- Is it okay to limit the usage of `startForeground(...)` for only **post Oreo** OS version

Comment: Yes it is ok to use it like this. It will run in the background in pre-oreo devices, but if the user kills your app, the service will die as well, unless you use `startForeground` for pre-oreo as well.

Comment: See [Background Execution Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background)

Comment: @HedeH, thanks for the reply... Could you please post it as an answer, so that I can accept. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> MyService should run in the background in both pre Oreo and post Oreo OS versions. Is it okay to limit the usage of startForeground(...) for only post Oreo OS version?

Yes it is ok to use it like this.

The `Service` will run in the background in `pre-oreo` devices, but if the user kills your app, the `Service` will also die, unless you use `startForeground` for pre-oreo as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @HedeH (Y)

Answer (score 0):

WorkManager is intended for tasks that require a guarantee that the system will run them, even if the app exits
**Start foreground looks well when your use case requires notification also ex: Backup, navigation, location updates.** Such operation start foreground fits perfectly.
**But there are other cases when it doesn't have to show notification.
Plus it should be always used when task is deferrable.**

> WorkManager uses an underlying job dispatching service when available
>   based on the following criteria:
>   Uses JobScheduler for API 23+ Uses a custom AlarmManager +
>   BroadcastReceiver implementation for API 14-22

link for more 
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager?hl=en